# Display returned JSON objects in a nice way

Tags: jquery, json

I was wondering if there is a way to display returning json objects from my server is a nice/pleasing way. IE Just show it on my webpage instead of an alert that I have now.

```
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert(data.details + '\nHello ' + data.clientInfo.firstName + ' ' + data.clientInfo.lastName + '. \nBalance:' + data.clientInfo.balance);
        }
```

This is what I have now. I have failed to make the data show up on my webpage. Any hints/tips/suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: iterate and create div using your data

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSONViewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu)

or if you want to format it programatically then to the following way

Programmatic formatting solution:

The JSON.stringify method supported by many modern browsers (including IE8) ([For Detailed Support List](http://caniuse.com/#search=JSON.stringify)) can output a better viewable JSON string:

```
JSON.stringify(jsObj, null, "\t"); 
JSON.stringify(jsObj, null, 5);
```

Fiddle For Your Code:[Sample JSON OUTPUT](http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/HZPVL/)

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to display the json contents directly using the template binding. You have to create a template with the class properties like below. I have copied the sample from Knockout.

```
<h2>Participants</h2>
Here are the participants:
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', data: buyer }"></div>
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', data: seller }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="person-template">
    <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
    <p>Credits: <span data-bind="text: credits"></span></p>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function MyViewModel() {
     this.buyer = { name: 'Franklin', credits: 250 };
     this.seller = { name: 'Mario', credits: 5800 };
 }
 ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
</script>
```

You can also use any other template technology.

Comment: thanks. I was wondering if I could also display the data in the body of the web page.